# Vue js bootstrap start filtering once button is clicked

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

How can I trigger the search filter once a button is clicked?
I don't want to filter each type that someone typing in the search bar.
I want to trigger searching once they click a button "Search Now".

```
<b-table
                        id="table-transition-example"
                        :busy.sync="loading"
                        :items="myProvider"
                        :fields="fields"
                        :current-page="currentPage"
                        :per-page="perPage"
                        striped
                        small
                        primary-key="user_id"
                        :filter="filter"
                        :sort-by="sortBy"
                        :sort-desc="sortDesc"
                        >
```

With this code anytime that someone typing in search bar, automatically search the table.

Can somehow to append :filter attribute if I create a custom event? OR any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a different data property to your input, and create a method that assigns the value from your input to your `filter` property.

**Rough example:**

```html
<input v-model="filterInput">
<button @click="applyFilter">Search now</button>

<b-table :filter="filterTable"></b-table>

<script>
data() {
  return {
    filterInput: '',
    filterTable: ''
  }
},
methods: {
  applyFilter() {
    this.filterTable = this.filterInput
  }
}
</script>
```